# How do i create One-to-One to relationship without having navigation property in dependent entity

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I understand the following code creates "One-to-One relationship" between a principal and a dependent entity.

However, I would like to ask:

1. Is it possible to create one-to-one relationship without including navigation property in the dependent entity?
2. If yes, than how should I re-write the following code?

   ```
   public class Student
   {
       [Key]
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string FullName { get; set; }

       public StudentReport StudentReport { get; set; }
   }

   public class StudentReport
   {
       [Key, ForeignKey("Student")]
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string RollNumber { get; set; }
       public string StudentType { get; set; }

       public Student Student { get; set; }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a one-to-one relationship without a navigation property on the dependent side, you'll need to use the [fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#RequiredToOptional). For example, in your `DbContext` class, you can override `OnModelCreating` and use this to define the relationship:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // I'm assuming the report is optional
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>() 
        .HasOptional(t => t.StudentReport) 
        .WithRequired();
}
```

```
public class StudentReport
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RollNumber { get; set; }
    public string StudentType { get; set; }
}
```

*See documentation for `WithRequired()` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696456(v=vs.113).aspx)*

Comment: thanks for your answer. What about foreign key? So, with your example above i assume 'Id' in 'StudentReport' (dependant) entity will be Primary Key as well as Foreign key. Correct me please if i am wrong?

Comment: 2nd point: With your approach (Fluent API), Do i still require to define navigation property inside Principle entity (Student)? i.e. public StudentReport StudentReport { get; set; }

Comment: @immirza: By default, when there's a one-to-one relationship in EF, the dependent entity's primary key is used as the foreign key. If you're using code first, at least one of the entities in the relationship needs to have a navigation property (otherwise, how would EF know the entities are related?)

Comment: thanks excellent point i was not aware. Another thing, I already have code in my DBContext class for 'Cascade deletion' for above example.  i.e. modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasOptional(x => x.StudentReport).WithOptionalDependent().WillCascadeOnDelete(); So this code will remain untouched if i go with your proposed changes above?

Comment: @immirza: that statement might overwrite the `HasOptional(..).WithRequired()` since it's defining a different relationship with the same entities and the same navigation property. If you wanted to, you could add `.WillCascadeOnDelete()` after `WithRequired()`, though I think it should cascade delete by default if you set `Student` as required for each `StudentReport`.

Comment: @ jjj. Thanks its clear except the last line.. "though I think it should cascade delete by default if you set Student as required for each StudentReport" .. Where i can set Student as required for each StudentReport"?

Comment: @immirza: The answer above sets `Student` as required for `StudentReport`. If you had a `StudentReport.Student` navigation property, it would be `WithRequired(sr => sr.Student)`, but since you're not planning to have a navigation property in that direction, it's implied that when you have `WithRequired()`, `Student` is what's required. You could imagine it as a sentence: "A Student has an optional StudentReport with a required (Student)."